# What's the easiest way to connect external database and display data on wordpress?

Tags: database, sql

I want to use google cloud sql for keeping my data. The data is changeable from another application. I give necessary permissions to cloud sql but I cannot find easier way to show the data on the wordpress site. My first choice will be plugins or custom arrangements. Of course if I had to write code, I would do.

Comment: You just need to use the correct address for your database when setting up WordPress: https://geekflare.com/google-cloud-sql-wordpress/

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for the link, but I've already done most of them. I can reach the google sql database from the phpmyadmin but serverchoice is different with my wordpress-root password. I just do not know how to show that databese on the site.